# Write a function that takes a list of numeric grades and returns their letter grades

Tags: function, if-statement

#trying to get this function to work full of ifs elifs and elses. Please help

```
def letter_grade_list(grade):
    return["A" if i>=90 "B" elif i>=80 and i<=89 "C" elif i>=70 and i<=79 "D" elif i>=60 and i<69 
    else "F" for i in grade]
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I keep getting this error: 

 File "<ipython-input-93-df4a07ebdd21>", line 2
    return["A" if i>=90 "B" elif i>=80 and i<=89 "C" elif i>=70 and i<=79 "D" elif i>=60 and i<69 else "F" for i in grade]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Just solved it!  def letter_grade_list(grade):
    return["A" if i>=90 else "B" if i>=80 and i<=89 else "C" if i>=70 and i<=79 else "D" if i>=60 and i<69 else "F" for i in grade]

ELIFS DID NOT WORK for else and ifs did.

Comment: If you solve your own question do you win stack overflow?

Comment: You only win if you post your solution as an _Answer_, not a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.